# Button's touch area on iPhone's Safari is different from iPad's

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari, mediaelement.js

Load [this page](http://lancelot.dlib.indiana.edu/media_objects/avalon:914) on an iPhone, you will see a video player with a cog icon on the control bar. Directly touching this button will not register anything, but if you touch a bit outside to the right, it will fire a hover event. The popup radio list is not selectable either.

All of these work on an iPad. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out that the `<video>` element on iPhone Safari will block all touch events. The workaround I use is to reduce its dimension to 1px*1px and always show the poster image, giving the illusion of an actual video. Youtube employs the same workaround.

P/S: the link above may change over time.